# CCnet + NAnt Time Out

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net, nant, ccnet-config

I am unable to execute Nunit test  through Nant which in turn is called by CCNet.
Below is the Error msg which i get in CCnet Dashboard:

> <exception>
>     <![CDATA[ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.BuilderException:
>   NAnt process timed out (after 900
>   seconds)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.NAntTask.Execute(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Tasks.TaskBase.Run(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Project.RunTask(ITask
>   task, IIntegrationResult result,
>   Boolean isPublisher)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Project.RunTasks(IIntegrationResult
>   result, IList tasksToRun, Dictionary`2
>   parameterValues)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.Project.Run(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Build(IIntegrationResult
>   result)    at
>   ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Core.IntegrationRunner.Integrate(IntegrationRequest
>   request) BaseDirectory: , Targets: ,
>   Executable:
>   D:/AutomatedTestSuite/src/Automated
>   Testing/setup/SupportingTools/NAnt/bin/nant.exe,
>   BuildFile:
>   "D:/AutomatedTestSuite/src/Automated
>   Testing/setup/Practicemanagementsetup/practice_nunittestrunner.build"]]>
>   </exception>

I looked in CCnet.log file but did't find any info about the above activity.
Note: I am able to execute Nunit through Nant in command line. But it fails only when i try to execute through CCnet.
Please help me on this.

Comment: Error Detail (CCnet Dashboard):

Comment: Can you post the error detail please?

Answer (score 3):

There are two possible reasons why this may have been happening:

Depending on how long the NAnt task took, 900 seconds (15 minutes) may not have been enough - although I would certainly hope it is! If that is the case, editing the ccnet-config file and setting the buildTimeoutSeconds value should fix the problem. (See the [NAnt Task](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/NAnt+Task) documentation for details).

Another possibility, and perhaps a more likely one, is that the NAnt task is failing to recognize that the NAnt process has completed. This was a known issue with some versions of CCNet - see the bug reports for [CCNET-1735](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1735) and [CCNET-1789](http://jira.public.thoughtworks.org/browse/CCNET-1789). You may find that the issue has been resolved by a more recent CCNet build, if not I recommend checking with the [CCNet User Group](https://groups.google.com/group/ccnet-user).